# Proving the equality of two outer measures in a special case

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I would like some help with this question from Bartle's "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure":

(Here $\mu^{\star}(A) = \text{inf} \{ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_i): E_i \in \Omega, A \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} E_i\}$.)

> 9.N Let $X$ be a set, $\Omega$ an algebra of subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ a measure on $\Omega$. If $B$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$, let $\mu'(B)$ be defined to be
>   $$\mu'(B) = \text{inf} \{\mu(B): B \subseteq A \in \Omega \}$$ 
>   Show that $\mu'(E) = \mu(E)$ for all $E$ in $\Omega$ and that $\mu^{\star}(B) \leq \mu'(B)$. Moreover, $\mu^{\star} = \mu'$ in case $X$ is the countable union of sets with finite $\mu$-measure. Is $\mu'$ countably additive in the sense of 9.5(e)?

I don't know how to prove the equality mentioned in the "Moreover (...)" part.

I keep thinking of this "counter-example", and I don't know what is wrong with it: $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ is the usual length function, and $B = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty (n, n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}]$, and then $\mu^{\star}(B) = 1$ but every finite union of intervals that contains $B$ would have to have some interval of the form $(a,\infty)$, in which case $\mu'(B) = \infty$.

I've searched the internet but couldn't find anything related. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you mean $n = 1$ in your union $B$?

Comment: @Casquibaldo My mistake. I did mean that, I'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: I may be wrong, but what I am noticing is that the condition placed on $X$ after the "Moreover..." implies your measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.The sets $A$ of which $B$ would be a subset of could be $(n, n + 1]$ and you get the measure you are supposed to.

Comment: @Casquibaldo I don't follow. In my example, $B$ is that infinite union, so if $A$ were to contain $B$, are you proposing $A = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (n,n+1]$ ? (in which case $\mu'(A) = \infty > \mu^{\star} (A)$)

Comment: @Casquibaldo ... sorry, and in addition to that, $A$ wouldn't necessarily be in $\Omega$, since the algebra only (necessarily) contains the finite unions of intervals.

Comment: @Casquibaldo I don´t really think that $X$ needing to be in the algebra is an impediment, since, for instance, $\mathbb{R}$ fits in this category and the algebra that gives rise to the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra still exists, you just have to define $\mu(X) = \infty$.

Comment: You are right. I am now also puzzled by the book's statement!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70087/discussion-between-casquibaldo-and-mlaci).